# Is it possible to render a twig template for "later use"?

Tags: theming, 8

I have been asked to create a custom module that outputs a node's content in a way that it will be easy to print or export to pdf.

I came accross [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20957252/3628383) and this is litteraly what I'd like to do, but I can't manage to adapt it to Drupal. I've seen quite a lot of potential solutions, but I don't know if they'd help.

Here is what I did so far:

```
// My module's route is '/pdf/node/{nid}

$route_match = \Drupal::service('current_route_match');
$node = $route_match->getParameter('nid');
$node_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');
$result = $node_storage->load($node);

$response['title'] = $result->getTitle();
$path = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/modules/custom/mymodule_pdf/templates/node.html.twig';

// It would look like so:
$template = $this->get('twig')->render($path, 'title' => $response['title']);
```

So far, the twig file just contains the following:

```
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
```

So `$twig` would contain `<h1>The node's title</h1>`

And all I'd need to to is to put the $twig content as my future pdf's content, but this is the easiest part.

Is this possible to do this?

Comment: In what class did you place that code snippet? Also are you aware of dedicated modules like [Entity Print](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_print) that are designed to print Views content to pdf? All you need to do is get your entity in views and specify a render mode.

Comment: I know about entity print, however I have trouble making it work (it requires a dompdf version that is already installed but it doesn't work anyway)
For the snippet, this is in the module's "main" controller

Comment: Render the node and run it through the wkhtmltopdf, what's complicated about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you don't render twig templates directly, but build the content in a render array and use the render service:

```
public function nodeExportPdf(NodeInterface $node) {
  $view_builder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('node');
  $build = $view_builder->view($node, 'full');
  $html = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($build);
  ...
}
```

This will use the node template configured for the view mode you specify in the view builder. In this example `full`, but probably you want to create a custom view mode for the pdf.

When you are in a controller you get the route parameters in the function arguments. How to build the route for this see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/using-parameters-in-routes

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I have one last noob question, how do I setup my own template ? (this one doesn't show everything) Do I need to define it in a theme_hook() then call it instead of `full`?

Comment: Nevermind, I found out by myself

Comment: @Jaeger ok so what was the answer to this?

Comment: I don't exactly remember, but I do remember it was indeed a noob question... Just try@4k4's answer by yourself, if I remember well I didn't empty the cache so it didn't work at first (hope it will work for you)