# Get html of node programmatically with custom twig template applied

Tags: 8, theming, nodes

I am trying to get the html of a node("Destination" content type) and render it via a custom function.
My code looks something like:

```
$entity_type = 'node';
$node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($entity_type)->load(31140);
$renderable = [
  '#theme' => 'node__destination',
  '#node' => $node,
];
$t =  \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($renderable)->__toString();

dpm($t);
```

Am I missing something in the process?

Comment: What is the output of `$t` then?

Comment: The default node template

Comment: I've seen your comment here https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/245218/is-it-possible-to-render-a-twig-template-for-later-use/245223?noredirect=1#comment319888_245223. Why not use the view builder to build $renderable? If this is to generate a content type specific theme name, then you can use the template `node--destination.html.twig` right away, Drupal adds the content type name automatically (and the view mode you specify in the view builder, often you combine those two). If not I think you need to tell more about what you want to achieve.

Comment: What I'd like to do is get the content and make it accessible as part of a service which will return content along with other data related to the node.

Comment: This is not very specific, a generic answer would be: [Entities are now rendered by a view builder](https://www.drupal.org/node/1819308)